# How to Bend profiled rectangle exactly to 45 degrees?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, bevel

I have these profiled rectangle.
I need to Bend it around Z-axis (Face #2 need to go to right) thus angle between faces #1 and #2 be exactly 45 degress.

File: [image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is rather easy to do.

Just add a *Simple Deform Modifier*.
Set it to *Bend* and select the right axis.
Enter the desired angle (it's 45° by default)

[image]

**Note:**
In this case bending along the Z axis doesn't work as expected.
To make it work, rotate the *object's origin* by -90°, or use an *empty* rotated by -90°.

[image]

*Thanks to @lemon, @plem and @robin-betts for pointing that out.*

Comment: I did what you wrote and got another result. http://prntscr.com/qwt7tv

Comment: IMHO, you should indicate the little needed adjustments: figure rotation and origin point position, etc. As, if not, that won't work directly on his file.

Comment: @lemon I saw he adjusted Origin to the Corner. And What about figure rotation?

Comment: @lemon I was needed to do Apply Rotation via Ctrl+A

Comment: @lemon Thanks for the suggestions. The origin point location isn't that important, it only changes the diameter. But I can't get the bending work on the Z axis. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ I wanted to ask the same question. I did it as you did while Rect stand straight up, but could't achieve it when it lays as in my file at start. http://prntscr.com/qwthgm

Comment: Personally I find all the Simple Deform variants _much_ less confusing, when used with an axis/orientation  Empty, rotating it, and sticking to one axis. The rules about which axis the deformation is measured along for a given deformation axis are not entirely consistent, as far as I can tell, through trial and error.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ, have never been able to understand clearly the bending rules. I think there are questions about it here. But nothing totally satisfying. Practically, as we know what this is supposed to do, I'd say "just try rotating until the result is obtained". And yes, as Robin said this is easier using an empty as axis origin.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the advice, I edited the answer accordingly :).