# Modeling rockers (Rocker rail's) for a chair

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm trying to figure out how to make the edges on the rockers (Rocker rail's) round without affecting anything else as shown in the reference photo [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use proportional editing for the round ends and *Simple Deform* for the bent shape.

Use proportional editing with *Sphere faloff* for the ends.

[image]

Use *Simple Deform modifier* set to *Bend* for the bent shape

[image]

Comment: I'm matching your settings for the deform modifier, But I am getting a far different result. I have the z axis selected but it's torquing my object in a weird way

Comment: Yeah, the simple deform modifier is sometimes weird. This answer should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165766/78972

Comment: Thank you, That fixed it