# Bending/deforming complex geometries

Tags: modeling, animation

I am trying to bend a complex plate geometry, using the simple deform modifier however I am not getting the results I wanted.

[image]

Instead, after bending it looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? This is what the geometry looks like by the way:

[image]

Comment: Check if your deform modifier is limited to a vertex group, or upload the blend file if you can.

Comment: It's a question of object orientation, it bends the wrong way, try first to apply its rotation and see what you get

Comment: I never use a simple deform.  An armature modifier is better for any "simple" deformation I want.  Your topo here isn't great, and it will impact whatever you do.   You can't get a better deform than you have verts/topo.  Consider subdivision before modifiers here.  Pics of goal, and of course .blend file, would help people help you.

Comment: Hi :). Simple Deform modifier sometimes acts up, and you need to rotate your origin point to make it work correctly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165766/78972